# WPF Custom control and binding property

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I'm working on a custom ListView. In this scope I want to define a custom GridViewColumn that has a CellBinding property which is itself a BindingBase.

This property is defined like this:

```
public class GridViewColumn : System.Windows.Controls.GridViewColumn
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CellBindingProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached( "CellBinding", typeof( BindingBase ), typeof( GridViewColumn ),
            new PropertyMetadata( null, new PropertyChangedCallback( OnCellBindingChanged ) ) );

    public BindingBase CellBinding
    {
        get => (BindingBase)this.GetValue( CellBindingProperty );
        set => this.SetValue( CellBindingProperty, value );
    }...
```

All works fine in the xaml editor and this property seems to be recognized correctly:

```
     <wpfTools:GridViewColumn Header="Titre2" SortProperty="B" CellAlignement="Right" CellBinding="{Binding B}"/>
```

But when I want to use this property at runtime, the result of *column.CellBinding* is always null.
Please, why?

Comment: And what is B? property of what? you know that `GridViewColumn` `DataContext` is parent `DataContext` not "row/item" `DataContext`

Comment: What are you expecting to gain from this, other than obfuscating base functionality?  If you want to increase the diagnostics of the bindings add this xmlns to your window:
xmlns:diag="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase" 
then in your binding add:
diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High 
when you are running it will pump info into your output window.

Comment: @Selvin B is some property of objects in the data context. What I do not get here is why the property is just not set at runtime (null). Other property types I've coded the same way work fine, but not this one. Is it because this is a binding itself?

Comment: @KevinCook My aim is just simplifying the xaml needed to aim some ListView behavior. Productivity purpose. But the point here is simply that the value set in the editor is null at runtime (I'm not even talking about this data usage), just it is null and I don't get why.

Comment: Because B is null or not exists ... look for `System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'B' property not found on ...` in Debug output if you set DataContext of parent **again parent not `ItemsSource`**

Comment: With [MainWindow.xaml.cs](https://pastebin.com/BJRvHf8a)
[MainWindow.xaml](https://pastebin.com/KC4inJhc) it is not null

Comment: @Selvin, thanks I understand a bit better now. What I want to do I not binding 'CellBinding' but do so 'CellBinding' is a binding itself. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: As a note, using RegisterAttached for a regular dependency property (instead of an attached property) is wrong. Use `DependencyProperty.Register` instead. Besides that, `CellBinding` could as well be a regular CLR property instead of a dependency property, because it doesn't need to be bindable. You just *assign* a Binding in XAML to a property of type BindingBase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CellBinding` should *not* be a dependency property if it is supposed to be set to a `BindingBase`.

You should implement it as a CLR property and then implement your `GridViewColumn` class to apply the binding to the generated cell element as required:

```
public class GridViewColumn : System.Windows.Controls.GridViewColumn
{
    private BindingBase _cellBinding;
    public BindingBase CellBinding
    {
        get => _cellBinding;
        set => _cellBinding = value;
    }
    //...
}
```

Getting the value of a depenendency property evaluates the binding which is not what you want with a `BindingBase` property.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand much better how it works now.